# Conditionally format my HTML report using stored procedures?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I developed this code using SQL Server stored procedures and HTML to send out an automated report that checks for discrepancies in data, but I want to highlight numbers that are not equal to 0 in the delta column. Is there a way to highlight zero's in red(for example) and non-zero's in green ?

[I have attached the report here with the part highlighted in yellow that needs to be highlighted by HTML conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nFhp.jpg)

```
SET @tableHTML1 = 
    + N' <p>This report is driven by <b>DWQC.dbo.mwsp_QC_EM_LS_EPMS_DAILY_CHECK  </b> stored procedure.
            Each METRIC in the QC is compared between the Source,House and Mart databases,  
            and the resulting delta is displayed </p>'
     
    +N'<style type="text/css">' + N'.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aaa;}'
    + N'.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}'
    + N'.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;background-color:#808080;}'
    + N'.tg .tg-9ajh{font-weight:bold;background-color:#808080}' + N'.tg .tg-hgcj{font-weight:bold;text-align:center}'
    + N'</style>' -- contains all the styling for the HTML report
    + N'<table class="tg">'  -- calls the table to included in the report
    + N'<th class="tg-hgcj">CHECK_ID </th>'
    + N'<th class="tg-hgcj">CHECK NAME </th>'
    + N'<th class="tg-hgcj">SOURCE_COUNT</th>'
    + N'<th class="tg-hgcj">TARGET_COUNT</th>'
    + N'<th class="tg-hgcj">DELTA</th>' 
    + N'</tr>'   
    + CAST ( (select  -- checks for columns that could be seen in attached report
                td=CHECK_ID,'',
                td=CHECK_NAME,'',   
                td=SOURCE_COUNT,'', 
                td=TARGET_COUNT,'', 
                td=DELTA,'' 
            from( Select top 1000
            isnull(CHECK_ID,0) as CHECK_ID,     
            isnull(CHECK_NAME,0) as CHECK_NAME, 
            isnull(SOURCE_COUNT,0) as SOURCE_COUNT, 
            isnull(TARGET_COUNT,0) as TARGET_COUNT, 
            isnull(DELTA,0) as DELTA 
            from #table  --contains the data to be used in the report; temporarily naming it "table"
            order by RID)Q
                    FOR XML PATH('tr'),
                     TYPE
                    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                    + N'</table>'
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use CSS background-color?

Comment: This is just so wrong… SQL Server has a reporting engine built-in, use it instead of reinventing your own Frankenstein’s Reporting Monster.

Comment: *Is there a way to do that* - you haven't said what you want *that* to be - only you know how you want it displayed - 50pt glowing text with flashing border?. It's probably a good idea, if you *are* going to build HTML formatted output, to keep it separate from your qeries.

Comment: Simple to use a reporting engine but I need to kick-off these procs immediately after my ETL job completes. So I integrate these procs with ETL jobs.

Comment: Edited my question @Stu

Comment: Just create a function that takes a value and returns a string; it checks the value=0 and wraps it in a tag with a class for the relevant style element.

Answer (score 0):

..

```
td=TARGET_COUNT,'', 
[td/@class]=case when DELTA > 0 then 'highlightmeclass' end, 
 -- Or… [td/@bgcolor]= case when DELTA > 0 then 'yellow' end,
td=DELTA,''
```

..

Comment: this did not work for me. What do you call this concept? Maybe I could learn and try cases.

Comment: ..@DR222 ..edit

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 